# PDO : get a list of unique similar part of value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm fetching data with PDO from a table containing 2 fields : *comment* and *date*.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 extract($row);
 echo $comment;
 echo $date;
}
```

Which displays a list of all comments.

Now I'm trying to group these comments by month, the main goal is to create some filter menu with a GET value so that only the current month comments are displayed :

```
<ul>
<li><a href="comments.php?month=1014">October 2014</a></li>
<li><a href="comments.php?month=1114">November 2014</a></li>
<li><a href="comments.php">December 2014</a></li>
</ul>
```

I think I should be fine with the LIKE operator for displaying the results, but what about the menu links generation ?

**Main issue** : $date is in d/m/Y format, so I have to process before using it :

```
$created = $date;
$month = $created->format('mY');
```

Also I can't really know in advance which months are going to be registered in the table, so it have to be "dynamic".

**So how do I get a list of every month appearing in the table ?** Without redundancy of course. Like

```
1014
1114
1214
```

even if there is numerous comments created on October for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's STR_TO_DATE and DATE_FORMAT functions to return the date in the format you need. For example:

```
SELECT `comment`, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%m%y") as `date2` FROM `data`
```

If you need to query all the unique month/year combinations, use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%m%y") as `date2` FROM `data`
```

Here's a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03222/1) showing the distinct select.